What are efficient techniques for rotating multiple vectors in high-dimensional spaces?
I want to rotate a set of n vectors in an arbitrary dimension D, what I'm trying to do is to find a good sequence of angles to rotate the set fitting a density function, but incresing D, this take a lot of time (using matrices), so, I'm reading about using quaternions to get a faster way to test rotations, and I'm looking for the best way to do this.
I tried using the matrix approach, I've been reading about other approaches but I'm not sure what is the best way, because I want to try genetic algorithms to find these rotations, and need a good and fast way to apply it quickly.

Quaternions will only rotate 3D vectors. If you have a massively parallel operation, e.g. applying the same rotation matrix to a large number of vectors, then consider using a GPU.
